# How to find window name in selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

As per Selenium WebDriver documentation we can pass either name Or Handle to driver.switchTo().window(nameOrHandle); To get handle we have getWindowHandle. How to switch on new window based on window name? How to get current Window Name?

/

> **
> * Switch the focus of future commands for this driver to the window with the given name/handle.
> *
>
> * See [W3C WebDriver
> specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#switch-to-window)
> * for more details.
> *
> * @param nameOrHandle The name of the window or the handle as returned by
> *        {@link WebDriver#getWindowHandle()}
> * @return This driver focused on the given window
> * @throws NoSuchWindowException If the window cannot be found
> */
> WebDriver window(String nameOrHandle);

Answer (score 0):

Name is title of web page.

WebDriver.getTitle()

Comment: I don't think so...isn't name the value you use when calling window.open or the target of the link (in each case, the opened window can have whatever title it wants)?

Comment: see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name